# Embedding Derby File Creation

Tags: java, derby

I need help with Derby Embedded Connection. I know it's outdated, and I should use MS Access, but I need this one time.

I have tried to link through the Embedded Driver in Netbeans 7.3.1, again, I know this stuff is ancient, but it is what we are required to use. I cant show any code, because there isn't any.

Here are the steps I followed:

1. I selected Entity Classes from Database, and was presented with a
   Connection UI. I selected new connection, and selected the derby.jar
   file, and the derbyclient.jar file
2. Next, I have to give the URL to the database itself. I use the
   following: C:\Users\User\.netbeans-derby\TestDB, its a localhost
   table created in Services-Databases
3. I then inputted the login credentials and tried Test Connection, It
   says the connection has failed because it cannot establish a link
   using the following driver :

Is there another way to link a table via Derby? OR can someone please enlighten me as to what I am doing wrong?

Many, Many Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the full error message and stack trace from step (3)? It looks like your question was truncated or you had some problem pasting in the actual error message.

Comment: Hi Bryan. I have found out what the problem was. The problem was that the database was already connected and was accepting connections on port 1527. What I had to do was locate the database, move it to the project folder, and disconnect the file from the IDE, and that solved the  problem. After that I changed the URL, and it works perfectly! The thing that had me puzzling for 3 weeks was one click away! Now if only I can write SQL to the database... The error code was 40000

Comment: @BryanPendleton Heres the error 'Unable to add conection. Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:derby:mydatabasename using org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver (Database 'mydatabasename' not found.).' Even with the location of the DB, it still failed